# Sorting in Rails views without displaying duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, erb

How do I sort in Rails view but without displaying any duplicate values?

I have the following ERB code.

```
  <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <h1><%= todo.due %></h1>
    <br />
    <%= todo.description %><b><%= todo.list %></b>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

And will output the following:

> **2011-03-09 10:39:00 -0600**
>
> My Todo For Today **My List**
>
> **2011-03-09 10:39:00 GMT**
>
> My Another Todo for Today **My List 2**
>
> **2011-03-09 10:39:00 GMT**
>
> And Another Todo for Today **My List**

However, how do I make it output with the following format in Rails?

> **2011-03-09 10:39:00 GMT**
>
> My Todo For Today **My List**
>
> And Another Todo for Today **My List**
>
> My Another Todo for Today **My List 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a method to todo model, that returns list of items by a due date:

```
#models/todo.rb    
def self.get_todo_by_due(due_date)
   return Todo.where(:due => due_date)
end
```

And then change view:

```
<%distinct_due_dates = Todo.select("DISTINCT(due)") %>

<%distinct_due_dates.each do |item|%>
  <% due_date = item.due %>
  <h1><%= due_date %></h1>
  <% get_todo_by_due(due_date).each do |todo|%>
    <br />
    <%= todo.description %><b><%= todo.list %></b>
    <br />
  <% end%>
<% end%>
```

Comment: You could also use `Todo.find_by_due`

Answer (score 2):

`@todos` is an Array and [@todos.uniq!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000277) removes duplicates. There is a method [sort!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000245) in the Array class which should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `group_by` method

```
<% @todos.group_by(&:due).each do |due, todos| %>
  <h1><%= due %></h1>
  <% todos.each do |todo| %>
    <p><%= todo.description %> <b><%= todo.list %></b></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```